# How do I delete the background of my last DIV element?

Tags: html, css

How do I delete the background of my last DIV using `class="item"`?

Parent is: `<div id="lastQuestions"></div>`

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YAAK2/5/)

Comment: Show more of your HTML.

Comment: Have updated my fiddle is it good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could use a different html tag (like `span`, `p` or `li` displayed as block) for the`.item` elements instead of `div` to differentiate them from other `div` elements, and then you can do something like:

```
#lastQuestions li:last-of-type {
    background: none;
}
```

to select it.

[quick illustration](http://jsfiddle.net/YAAK2/1/)

### Edit:

Since, according to your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YAAK2/5/), only `.item` elements are of type `div` in your code they already differ in type from all other children of `#lastQuestions`. So you can just try this:

```
#lastQuestions > div:last-of-type {
    background: none;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YAAK2/6/)

Answer (score 4):

```
.item:last-child {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

Use pseudo element last-child

Here is a [**working jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/rReww/3)

Comment: I would change the selector to be `#lastQuestions div.item:last-child` to better fit the OP's situation.

Comment: #Right .lastQuestions .item:last-child {
    background: none;
} Does not work

Comment: I would further improve your answer by adding the `.item` to the selector for the `item` class. You can also set the background to `transparent` instead, which I believe is the default background color. Although, `inherit` may also work. :)

Comment: @user2568107 thanks. but if you add anything else after the last div it does not work  ... it seems only to work when the element with this class is also the very last child at the same time.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted

Comment: I will change the fiddle to make the background of the last element to red\

Comment: @user2568107 You don't need to change the color. How I understood the OP is: "How to select the last occurring element with class `.item`, where it is not necessary the last child of the parent container". And I think `last-child` does not manage to do that.

Comment: Have changed so it is last-child of all elements

Comment: I don't get what you are saying??

Comment: S you should probably add this fiddle to your answer and also add, that the OP needs to make sure the last div of class `.item` is also the last overall element in the parent container. Which you achieved by putting the link to the outside of the container.